Setting an interface's property type to fixed length array
Is it possible to set the length of the coordinates array to 2?
interface MapCoordinates {
    type: 'POINT';
    coordinates: Array<number>;
}

Using the interface:
var point = { type: 'Point', coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722]};


You are looking for a Tuple. Here is a pro lesson: https://booleanart.com/course/typescript/arrays?gift=vo9kpmpxtui

You are looking for a tuple (fixed length array).
Here is the same type using a tuple:
interface MapCoordinates {
    type: 'POINT';
    coordinates: [number, number];
}

let point: MapCoordinates = { type: 'POINT', coordinates: [39.807222,-76.984722]};


Also, don't forget to assign the type when creating the variable: var point: MapCoordinates;

@VinayakVohra Thanks. I've updated my answer to include that.

You can either make it a tuple:
interface MapCoordinates {
    type: 'POINT';
    coordinates: [number, number];
}

or define your own type, for custom fixed length:
type FixedLengthArray<T, N extends number> = T[] & { length: N };
interface MapCoordinates {
    type: 'POINT';
    coordinates: FixedLengthArray<number, 2>;
}

// Usage:
var point: MapCoordinates = { type: 'POINT', coordinates: [39.807222, -76.984722] };

Explanation:

T[]: this part describes a "normal array" of type T.
& { length: N }: this part means that the length property of this array is no longer just a number. Instead, it’s specifically the number N.
So now, only arrays with length = N can be assigned to the variable of type FixedLengthArray.

let validArray: FixedLengthArray<number, 3> = [1, 2, 3]; // Valid

let invalidArray: FixedLengthArray<number, 3> = [1, 2];  // Invalid
// Types of property 'length' are incompatible. 
// Type '2' is not assignable to type '3'.


If it does not work, you can replace T[] with [T, ...T[]].
